# keyCode simply giving... the wrong response

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure why this is happening. Similar things have happened, but they're typically due to keyloggers or something along those lines.

My javascript is simply bugging out, or something.

When I use [this](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) link and press W, I get 87 as a response.

However, when I run my own code, which looks simply like this:

```
var keydown = function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode); //I've also tried charCode
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", keydown, false);
```

I get the number 119 when I press W.

This is occurring both in Chrome and in IE.

What gives?

Comment: Your linked site displays `W` when you type `w`, it is not capturing the `shift` as a meta key. I don't think you cannot actually type this character in the text field.

Comment: It's because capital `W` is `87` and small(lower) `w` is `119`, make sure `caps lock` is in the same state when you press `w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `keyup` and `keydown` for identifying physical keys and `keypress`(redundant) is for identifying typed character so using `keypress` event, `W/capital`(87) and `w/lower`(119) gives different results but `keydown` will always give you `87`. So, as other answer stated, you should use `keydown`.

Read more on [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

> Therefore, onkeydown/up keyCode always holds the key code. onkeypress
>   you can find the actual character the user typed by evt.charCode ||
>   evt.keyCode.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

**Source:** http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Maybe you should use [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)?

Comment: There is no jQuery tag on the question and jQuery documentation is not authoritative for web specifications. See: [DOM Level 3 Events: keypress](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress).